# change background image, when big size umage loads

Tags: javascript, css

i have a div element, with very big size background image. so, is it possible, to set a little size image as backgrount, untill the big size image loads.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.that-div {
    background-image:url(/path/to/small-image.png);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var bigImg = new Image(),
        bigImgSrc = '/path/to/big-image.png';

    bigImg.src = bigImgSrc;

    $(bigImg).load(function(){
        $('.that-div').css('background-image':'url('+bigImgSrc+')');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should definitely suggest a pure JavaScript version.

Comment: i like you solution, thanks;) i'll use it's logic to write the same with javascript

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could put another `div` element underneath it (using the `z-index` property) and give that the faster loading background image.

Whether that is practical to do, depends on your Layout, you'd have to give more information about that.

There's also the ages-old [`lowsrc`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_lowsrc.asp) HTML 4 property that still seems to be pretty well supported (I have not tried it myself since Netscape 4), but that won't work for background images.

Comment: it's just a single <div>, but it hasn't position absolute( how i know, in that case i cant use Z-index?)

Comment: @Syom yup, then it becomes really difficult, especially if it has a variable height/width. If it doesn't, you may be able to put both above each other using `position: absolute`.